# Tool to check whether iPhone app is backward compatible

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am developing an iPhone app that needs to be compatible with iOS 4.x as well as iOS 3.x. Is there a tool that checks the code statically and informs me if a method/class isn't available in iOS 3.x? Classes like UIGestureRecognizer are available only on iOS 3.2 and higher.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Though I haven't done this yet, this question looks very useful for this question: [finding unsupported apis with os version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4381363/finding-unsupported-apis-with-os-version)

Hope this helps!